# Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

**spring-database**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.hello.hellospring" />
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />


    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.hello.hellospring.model</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
          class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">

    <display-name>Spring Security Bcrypt Application</display-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring-database.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springmvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springmvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <!-- Spring Security Filter -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**userDaoImpl.java**

```
package com.hello.hellospring.dao;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.hello.hellospring.model.User;


@Repository("userDao")
public class UserDaoImpl extends AbstractDao<Integer, User> implements UserDao {

    public void save(User user) {
        persist(user);
    }

    public User findById(int id) {
        return getByKey(id);
    }

    public User findBySSO(String sso) {
        Criteria crit = createEntityCriteria();
        crit.add(Restrictions.eq("ssoId", sso));
        return (User) crit.uniqueResult();
    }

}
```

Here is the class where I am getting error:

**AbstractDao.java**

```
package com.hello.hellospring.dao;

import java.io.Serializable;

import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;



public abstract class AbstractDao<PK extends Serializable, T> {

    private final Class<T> persistentClass;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public AbstractDao(){
        this.persistentClass =(Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[1];
    }

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Transactional
    protected Session getSession(){
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T getByKey(PK key) {
        return (T) getSession().get(persistentClass, key);
    }


    public void persist(T entity) {
        getSession().persist(entity);
    }


    public void delete(T entity) {
        getSession().delete(entity);
    }


    protected Criteria createEntityCriteria(){
        return getSession().createCriteria(persistentClass);
    }


}
```

I dont know whats wrong with that the issue i got is: please help me to solve this issue. Each time I run this code it is saying that I have some hibernate session issue. thanks :)

[image]
[image]

Comment: hi i have some problem with generic dao what is this solution  ?

Answer (score 0):

try annotating your class or methods with @Transactional. Declarative transaction boundaries will take out this exception.

Comment: you should provide the answer with detailed explanation along with CODE. If you are unsure, leave a comment instead of posting as a answer

Answer (score 0):

```
    package com.hello.hellospring.dao;

    import org.hibernate.Criteria;
    import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

    import com.hello.hellospring.model.User;


    @Repository("userDao")
   @Transactional
    public class UserDaoImpl extends AbstractDao<Integer, User> implements UserDao {

        public void save(User user) {
            persist(user);
        }

        public User findById(int id) {
            return getByKey(id);
        }

        public User findBySSO(String sso) {
            Criteria crit = createEntityCriteria();
            crit.add(Restrictions.eq("ssoId", sso));
            return (User) crit.uniqueResult();
        }

    }

You are missing a @Transactional annotation above this class read this http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/hibernate-transaction-annotation-config-code-example.html
```

Comment: I have tried this but still facing the same problem. I had applied @Transactionl in every services classes instead

Comment: its showing error in this line : protected Session getSession(){
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

Comment: dont put transactional everywhere ,just on the above of UserDaoImpl  class